# Gitlab CI clone does not know what main is

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to figure out what files have changed in an MR for automation.  My git command works fine locally (on git 2.39.x) but in git 2.30.0 on a gitlab runner, it doesn't understand what the main branch is.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I've tried changing the clone depth to 0, the `GIT_STRATEGY` to both clone and fetch, tried putting a `git fetch origin main` but it doesn't even understand that.  My repo absolutely has a `main` branch.  Gitlab can display it.  It's the default branch.  But some mechanism in Gitlab CI is unlike Git and I don't understand.

The following commands don't understand what ref I mean

```
git show main
git fetch origin main
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r main..head # this is what I'm trying to do
```

Comment: Try `origin/main` instead. `git fetch origin main` does not create a local `main`. If the git configuration is not correct, it does not create `origin/main` either. In a script, it's better to use `git fetch origin +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main` to make sure `origin/main` will be created or updated.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks.  It was a combination of that and case sensitivity in Linux.  This worked.  `export FILES_CHANGED=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r origin/main..HEAD)`

So, that `git show` probably won't work ahead of the `fetch`.